# Infowindow split string by comma

Tags: javascript, carto

I might have went about this the wrong way, though I thought it may be a good idea to ask before starting over again. I have a picture column in cartodb which has multiple picture ids separated by commas. So I created a script that would take those  values and parse the ids out into an a href tag. My question: Is there a way to grab the json value inside  infowindow template {{ photo_column}}  and run the value to my script?

```
var str = '7BC414B0-B38E-4A70-9464-65CCAEC39C8E,327CF268-6742-4E20-9C92-41E9945FCCBD';
var myarray = str.split(',');
var url = "https://web.fulcrumapp.com/api/v2/photos/";
var token = ".jpg?token=3231c4d7309903b454ac10da556778cdf775b72192a96b3";
    for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
       document.write("<li><a href=\"" + url + "" + myarray[i] + "" + token + "\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"" + url + "" + myarray[i] + "\"></a></li>");
```

Comment: not exactly sure what you're trying to do here...maybe include more code, a link to your web page, or a link to a jsfiddle example...?

Answer (score 1):

You can call a javascript method from the infowindow template, check this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/6029822

Comment: Thank you Javisantana  I was able to access the json photo column from the cartodb table and parse out the photos since there are many photos to one feature. however I am still having a difficult time formatting my function in order to get the photos to show up in the infowindow.  http://jsfiddle.net/CrazySpatial/9Hwcg/

Comment: could you provide a full working example?